# Using Ajax Correctly in WordPress plugin

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

i am trying to call AJAX in my custom plugin, but with no success. so i have tried to have a simple code written to check the ajax call, the thing is when i put the code in functions.php it works just fine. but when i put it in another file inside my plugin. it doesn't work. i don't know why. here is the simple code.

```
// This would normally be enqueued as a file, but for the sake of ease we will just print to the footer
function add_this_script_footer(){ ?>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // This is the variable we are passing via AJAX
    var fruit = 'Banana';

    // This does the ajax request (The Call).
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>", // Since WP 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined and points to admin-ajax.php
        data: {
            'action':'example_ajax_request', // This is our PHP function below
            'fruit' : fruit // This is the variable we are sending via AJAX
        },
        success:function(data) {
    // This outputs the result of the ajax request (The Callback)
            
            window.alert(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            window.alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });

});
</script>
<?php }

add_action('in_admin_footer', 'add_this_script_footer');

function example_ajax_request() {

    // The $_REQUEST contains all the data sent via AJAX from the Javascript call
    if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {

        $fruit = $_REQUEST['fruit'];

        // This bit is going to process our fruit variable into an Apple
        if ( $fruit == 'Banana' ) {
            $fruit = 'Apple';
        }

        // Now let's return the result to the Javascript function (The Callback)
        echo $fruit;
    }

    // Always die in functions echoing AJAX content
   die();
}

// This bit is a special action hook that works with the WordPress AJAX functionality.
add_action( 'wp_ajax_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
```

When i put it in functions.php , it alerts Apple just fine.

but when i put it inside a file, it alerts [object OBJECT].

i have tried to add

```
wp_localize_script('mypluginscript', 'ajax_object', array(
            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
        ));
```

and then change url:ajax_object.ajax_url in the data object, but still no succes and some times i get POST xxxx.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 .

Comment: If it alerts `[object OBJECT]`, it means `data` contains an object (rather than a string) and you can't  directly show an object on screen like that - it has no inherent visual representation. You could try `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` and see what you get.

Comment: ADyson
This didn't work, it returned POST URL/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400

Comment: Well at least you can now see there's a 400 error. Not being a wordpress expert, I can't help you much with the likely causes of that unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have everything set up correctly for the most part, but when you are moving the code to a separate file in your plugin, you need to properly enqueue the script and localize it to get the correct ajax URL. Here's a step-by-step process on how to do this:

1. Create a new JavaScript file in your plugin directory, let's call it **myplugin-ajax.js.**
2. Move the JavaScript code from your **add_this_script_footer()** function to the newly created **myplugin-ajax.js** file. Make sure to remove the  tags, as they are not needed in a separate JS file. Replace the **echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');** with **ajax_object.ajax_url** in the **url** parameter.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // This is the variable we are passing via AJAX
    var fruit = 'Banana';

    // This does the ajax request (The Call).
    $.ajax({
        url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
        data: {
            'action': 'example_ajax_request',
            'fruit': fruit
        },
        success: function(data) {
            window.alert(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown) {
            window.alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });

});
```

3. Now, let's properly enqueue and localize the script in your plugin file. Replace your **add_this_script_footer()** function with the following function:

```
function enqueue_myplugin_ajax_script() {
    // Register the script
    wp_register_script('myplugin-ajax', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'myplugin-ajax.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);

    // Localize the script with the correct ajax URL
    wp_localize_script('myplugin-ajax', 'ajax_object', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
    ));

    // Enqueue the script
    wp_enqueue_script('myplugin-ajax');
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_myplugin_ajax_script');
```

This function enqueues and localizes your **myplugin-ajax.js** file. Make sure to replace **plugin_dir_url(**FILE**) . 'myplugin-ajax.js'** with the correct path to your **myplugin-ajax.js** file if it's located in a subdirectory.

4. Remove the **add_action('in_admin_footer', 'add_this_script_footer');** line since you no longer need it.

Now, your AJAX call should work properly from your custom plugin file.

Comment: i have tried this, but unfortunate it returns with 400 error too, i'm enqueuing the scripts when the plugin is activated, and i can see that the script file is loaded under network tab in my browser dev tools, but i always get```Failed AJAX Call :( /// Return Data: [object Object]```

POST htttp://deemos.ga/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: you had the path issue, kindly double-check your path. As you said above that your code works in **functions.php** so you need to check the path and make sure that path is correct, if you use it in a folder then it will go like this `"/foldername/jsfile.js"`

Comment: 'htttp://deemos.ga/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' isn't this is the correct path for the admin ajax , and if you referring to the javascript file , actually it is registered fine as it has other functions and these functions is working just fine, exxcept the one that have ajax request in it

Comment: I am talking about your custom js code, in which you mentioned fruits.